# Send reminder 2 days before start time of calendar event in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

the background of this question is that our company is now using SharePoint 2007 and we can book a meeting room through the calendar, 
**we want to send email to remind people who have booked the meeting room 3 days before the starting time of the meeting.**
We tried to use workflow to send the reminders automatically but we failed, the workflow setting has paused on "in progress" stage.

We would like to ask is there any alternative way instead of using workflow can fulfill our target?

There are restrictions for us.
**1. We try to prevent using 3rd party tools.
2. We want to minimize the changes we made in the server.**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a TimerJob which could run on a daily basis and look at the meetings in the SharePoint List to send emails if it is needed.

I you already have NINTEX running in your Company this could also be an option. But default SP Workflows couldnt do this job.